# propertygrid object with custom editor like a slider

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, propertygrid

In my windowsForm application I use a PropertyGrid to edit the instances of my class: some of these properties are floating point with maximum and minimum item.

I wish modify them by a slider or something like it.

I've found this: http://www.visualhint.com/propertygrid but is not free..

do you have an idea to help me?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `TrackBar`. Note that `PropertyGrid` by default does not allow you to add controls like these to it. So, you will need to do some work here. You will need to create a class that inherits from `System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor`. Next you will have to set the editor attribute for the property that has to display track bar as control. Note that unless you do custom paint, it will be shown as modal dialog or as dropdown editor.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9517/PropertyGrid-and-Drop-Down-properties