# Add checkbox in the propertygrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

i used PropertyGrid control to display properties on gridview.
i have taken an reference of this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-property-grid-in-c-sharp/
which is showing like this [image]
[image]

But i need checkbox just before the property name shown in red mark **on check/uncheck for any property i need to build expression**.

Comment: `PropertyGrid` is not suitable for that requirement. You need to create the expression builder yourself. Maybe a `DataGridView` control is a better option. You also can create a custom composite control to satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this: [How do I change boolean properties with one click in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659850/how-do-i-change-boolean-properties-with-one-click-in-propertygrid).

It extends the PropertyGrid control and defines its checkbox controls using UITypeEditor.

Answer (score 0):

As Reza mentioned, your choice of control does not appear optimal. You should probably create a form with `TextBox`, `CheckBox`, `ComboBox` etc. Or make use of DataGridView if your display is catering for multiple records at same time.

If you most definitely want to customize `PropertyGrid`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357101/propertygrid-object-with-custom-editor-like-a-slider/22357839#22357839) is my another answer which might help you start with.

Linked answer:

> You can make use of TrackBar. Note that PropertyGrid by default does
>   not allow you to add controls like these to it. So, you will need to
>   do some work here. You will need to create a class that inherits from
>   System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor. Next you will have to set the
>   editor attribute for the property that has to display track bar as
>   control. Note that unless you do custom paint, it will be shown as
>   modal dialog or as dropdown editor.